# Meteor.JS Datatable Server Side Processing

Tags: mongodb, meteor, datatable, inline-editing

**What I have tried till now**

I am writing this because I have been trying with lot of things in Datatable for Meteor, I have use Reactive as well as non reactive packages for Data table including:

aldeed:tabular https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular
ephemer:reactive-datatables https://github.com/ephemer/meteor-reactive-datatables

I have to use fetch and display records from multiple collections in a data table, I have also tried  reywood:publish-composite in aldeed:tabular , it has an issue that we cannot search or sort data of child collection even it is displayed in the data table

Plus I have some custom requirements like inline edit ect (Tried Jeditable for Datatable).

Non Reactive Meteor Datatable Packages are causing issues related to reactivity and I have to refresh the page them to show them correctly which I don't want.

**My Question**

Does anyone knows how to do a Server Side Processing of Datatable with Meteor?
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/

I am using iron router so in order to fetch some data and pass to ajax call do I need to create a server side route in iron router?

Anyone if you can give some hint, that would be very helpful, I will then try to write some server side code and try and If I am successful then I will post solution here.

Any other recommendations other than Datatable are also welcome if that are closer to the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a Server Side Processing of Datatable with Meteor, you can user sipmle bootstrap datatable and along with that you can create your own server side pagination system. You can use projection along with the `{sort:sort, skip:skip, limit: perPage}`